# Is there any standard diagram to stack layer modeling of software architecture

Tags: architecture, stack, layer, modeling, diagram

If we do some search in google images for terms like "Software Stack Diagram" or "Software Architecture", we can see lots of stack diagram that represent the software architectures of lots of systems. Especially middlewares, operating systems, embedded software and etc get represent with these models of boxes and arrows. you can check links below.

Now the question is, are there any standard to these kinds of description, or just fellows do it in an intuitive way.

https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1782&bih=818&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=rVSwXL-HLYPSwAK9yI4w&q=software+stack+diagram&oq=software+stack+diagram&gs_l=img.3...0.0..18513...0.0..0.0.0.......1......gws-wiz-img.SzWXowZQuFk

https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1782&bih=818&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=alWwXIRozKXBArnQrKgO&q=software+architecture&oq=software+architecture&gs_l=img.12...0.0..3512...0.0..0.0.0.......1......gws-wiz-img.WzQ2bla1awY

I already checked UML, "4+1" View Model, and even less related design method like SSADM, but none of these design over the internet is exactly matched to these standards.

We on our company have already some internal standard for these representations, but if there is any good standard we prefer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check Clean Architecture and SOLID principles.

[Clean Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYt29.jpg)

Clean Architecture (Robert C. Martín AKA Uncle Bob) is a group of patterns, practices and principles focused on improve software quality and developer's productivity.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw Clean Architecture before sending the question. But the image that you sent is very generic about how to have a clean architecture, in other words, it shows the architecture should consist of which parts and how they contain each other.

My question is about a standard of how to "represent" an architecture of "your design"

Thank you again.